# How to remove debugging from outputting with nosetests

Tags: python, logging, stderr, nosetests

I am using nosetests to test several scripts. But when I run nosetests it prints out the logging. I know it stores logging info into sys.stderr. Does anyone know how to stop this from outputting to the screen?

I just want the test results to output like when you run unittest normally.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer,

```
nosetests test* --nologcapture --nocapture
```

Run this in the command line.

Thanks